# SQL - Pivot table from a multilayer SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a SELECT statement that is as follows:

```
SELECT

d.CODE,
a.ANAPARA - Isnull(b.ANAPARA,0) AS ANAPARA,
d.NAME_,
c.DUEDATE,
a.TAKSIT - Isnull(b.TAKSIT,0) AS TAKSIT,
e.CURCODE

FROM
(SELECT 
PARENTREF,
SUM(TOTAL) AS ANAPARA,
SUM(INTTOTAL) AS FAIZ,
SUM(BSMVTOTAL) AS BSMV,
SUM(KKDFTOTAL) AS KKDF,
SUM(TOTAL+INTTOTAL+BSMVTOTAL+KKDFTOTAL) AS TAKSIT

    FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
    WHERE TRANSTYPE = 0 
    GROUP BY PARENTREF) a 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
PARENTREF,
SUM(TOTAL) AS ANAPARA,
SUM(INTTOTAL) AS FAIZ,
SUM(BSMVTOTAL) AS BSMV,
SUM(KKDFTOTAL) AS KKDF,
SUM(TOTAL+INTTOTAL+BSMVTOTAL+KKDFTOTAL) AS TAKSIT
    FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
    WHERE TRANSTYPE = 1 
    GROUP BY PARENTREF) b 
ON a.PARENTREF = b.PARENTREF

INNER JOIN (SELECT
 PARENTREF,
 CREDITREF,
 DUEDATE,
 OPRDATE
 FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR) c
ON a.PARENTREF=c.PARENTREF

INNER JOIN LG_011_BNCREDITCARD d
ON c.CREDITREF=d.LOGICALREF

INNER JOIN L_CURRENCYLIST e
ON d.TRCURR=e.CURTYPE OR (d.TRCURR=0 AND e.CURTYPE=160)

WHERE e.FIRMNR=11
```

This Code produces a table as follows:

```
   CODE      ANAPARA             NAME_          DUEDATE      TAKSIT      CURCODE
    001       103.35          CAR LOAN       2015-01-01      150.01          USD
    002       106.89     CONSUMER LOAN       2015-03-10      190.35          EUR
    003       110.44          CAR LOAN       2015-04-20      200.51          YEN
    004       103.22          CAR LOAN       2015-05-04      150.02          EUR
```

There are only 3 `CURCODE` values (Currencies): `USD`, `EUR` and `YEN`

I want a PIVOT table on which `DUEDATE` is the x-axis, `CURCODE` is the y-axis and `TAKSIT` is aggregated. To demonstrate, I want the following table:

```
   CODE      ANAPARA             NAME_          DUEDATE          EUR        USD        YEN
    001       103.35          CAR LOAN       2015-01-01         NULL     150.01       NULL   
    002       106.89     CONSUMER LOAN       2015-03-10       190.35       NULL       NULL
    003       110.44          CAR LOAN       2015-04-20         NULL       NULL     200.51
    004       103.22          CAR LOAN       2015-05-04       150.02       NULL       NULL
```

THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of the complexity of your query, you can wrap it and then `PIVOT` it as follows, provided that the columns being pivoted match those returned from the inner select. I've assumed a `SUM` aggregation on `TAKSIT`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT * 
   FROM 
   YourReallyComplexQueryHere
) x
PIVOT
(
  SUM(TAKSIT)
  FOR CURCODE IN ([USD], [EUR], [YEN])
) xx;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34cc6/1)